# First python project: Boggle

Tags: python, project

I'm working on adding directionality to boggle so that the user can trace their path on the board game. I found some code that would help in laying down diagonal functioning to the program but I'm not exactly sure what the code means. It would help a lot if someone could explain the function posted below.

```
def valid_direction(x1, y1, x2, y2):        

    dy = y2 - y1     
    dx = x2 - x1    
    if dx == 0:
        return dy != 0
    elif dy == 0:
        return dx != 0
    else:
        return abs(dx) == abs(dy)
```

I also want to allow the user to input coordinates pertaining to a letter from a 16 letter square board. looks like this in the shell:

```
|w||e||b||e|    
|r||t||o||l|    
|e||t||a||e|    
|i||p||a||a|    
Enter coordinate:
```

The inputted coordinates get stored in     path = [] which I already wrote a function for. My goal is to actually get the function to work so that the user is prompted multiple times until they've finished entering an actual word. Here's the function

```
def validate_path(path):    

    word = word_from_path(path, board)    
    if valid_word(word):
        # is it value = value from while loop and the rest?
        value = word_value(word)
        print("Value of {} is {}".format(word, value))
        score += value
    else:
        print("Invalid word")

    return validate_path(path)
```

And part of the loop for the game

```
while game:

       curr_input = input("Enter coordinate: ")
    if curr_input == "quit":
        print("Your total score is:", score)   
        game = False
    elif curr_input == "done":
         validate_path(path)
```

Thanks so much to whoever spends the time reading all of this !

Comment: Do you plan on checking it against a dictionary or something similar?

Comment: The `valid_direction(x1, y1, x2, y2)` function is returning true if the x2, y2 position is a straight line from your x1, y1 position (including diagonal). So based on your 4x4 grid with i at position 0,0 and e at position 3,3 - moving from 0,0 to 0,2 (r) returns true while moving to 1,2 (t) would be false.

Answer (score 0):

The function `valid_direction` stores delta-y (change in y-coordinate) in `dy` and delta-x in `dx`. Then, the ensuing if statements have the following logic:

1. If the y-coordinate hasn't changed (`dy == 0`), then if `dx == 0` return `0` because the coordinates are the same and it's an invalid move, otherwise return `1`.
2. If the x-coordinate hasn't changed (`dx == 0`), do the same as in 1. except with y and x reversed.
3. If both x and y coordinates have changed (`dy != 0 and dx != 0`) then check if they've both changed by the same absolute amount. If so, then it's a diagonal move by that absolute amount and it returns `1`, otherwise it returns `0`.

I'm not sure if this is what you want for Boggle though, since I think you want strictly adjacent moves (or a move to a directly diagonal space), so to check a valid move between two points would be:

```
def valid_direction(x1, y1, x2, y2):        

    dy = y2 - y1     
    dx = x2 - x1
    if dx == 0:
        return abs(dy) == 1
    elif dy == 0:
        return abs(dx) == 1
    else:
        return abs(dx) == abs(dy) == 1
```

Which checks if subsequent moves' coordinates differ by exactly one. Or, more concisely put:

```
def valid_direction(x1, y1, x2, y2):        

    dy = y2 - y1     
    dx = x2 - x1
    if not dy and not dx:
        return 0
    return abs(dx) <= 1 and abs(dy) <= 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying!